# How to add elements to IList collection using a function

Tags: c#

I'm just trying to understand an example of WPF treeview.

My goal ist to populate a treeview with some items, stored in a List.

This is the example:

```
public class Person
{
    readonly List<Person> _children = new List<Person>();
    public IList<Person> Children
    {
        get { return _children; }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

//Some added nodes:
    public static Person GetFamilyTree()
    {
        // In a real app this method would access a database.
        return new Person
        {
            Name = "David Weatherbeam",
            Children =
            {
                new Person
                {
                    Name="Alberto Weatherbeam",
                    Children=
                    {
                        new Person
                        {
                            Name="Zena Hairmonger",
                            Children=
                            {
                                new Person
                                {
                                    Name="Sarah Applifunk",
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        new Person
                        {
                            Name="Jenny van Machoqueen",
                            Children=
                            {
                                new Person
                                {
                                    Name="Nick van Machoqueen",
                                },
                                new Person
                                {
                                    Name="Matilda Porcupinicus",
                                },
                                new Person
                                {
                                    Name="Bronco van Machoqueen",
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        };
    }
```

So far it works.
Now I'd like to replace the static persons unter the first parent node with a list that I created before, reading a file.

```
XDocument ecad = XDocument.Load(openFileDialog.FileName);

GlobalVar.persons = new List<Persons>();    //globally available list
Person person = null;

//Einlesen der XML-Datei in lokale Variable (Model)
foreach(XElement elem in ecad.Descendants("Variable"))
{
    if (elem.Element("Name") != null)
    {
        person = new Person(){ Name = elem.Element("Name").Value };
        persons.Add(person);
    }
}
```

Now I'd like to add these Persons to a root-person

```
//GlobalVar.List<Persons> persons
public static Person GetFamilyTree()
{
    return new Person{
        Name = "Family",
        Children = persons
    }
}
```

So how can I replace the `Children = new...` with the function that reads the data from file?

I'm really confused

Comment: Sorry my last comment was wrong. Because persons is a List and Children is the interface IList you should be okay with just _Children = persons_ without anything else?

Comment: What `Children = new...` do you want to replace? The `Children` can only be set to an `IList<Person>`. It doesn't matter where this comes from.

Comment: Oh yes, I thought also (and tried serveral approaches, also with `IList<person>`). What I think is confusing, Children is a readonly property but with the "static Children" it works, with the IList it doesn't (because of readonly). Can someone explain the difference, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I think is confusing, `Children` is a readonly property but with the "static Children" it works, with the IList it doesn't (because of readonly). Can someone explain the difference, please?

Your `GetFamilyTree()` method uses a nested object initializer. Please refer to Jon Skeet's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15784586/7252182) for more information.

If you intend to read data from some source and then set the `Children` property, you should add a setter to it. You can also remove the backing field:

```
public class Person
{
    public IList<Person> Children { get; set; } = new List<Person>();
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. It's a bit strange looking for a beginner ;) So I will do it as I always did with setter and getter.

Comment: Yes sure, sorry